# Extension for scheduling an interview

Tags: joomla-3.3.x, extensions

We need a form where people need to register for an interview, but we need to ensure a person can select multiple dates (like Dec 7, Dec 9, Dec 11) and times (9 a.m. on Dec 7, 11 a.m. on Dec 7, 3 p.m. on Dec 9 and 2 p.m., 4 p.m. for Dec 11) interview. Also, the next person choosing a date/time cannot select a date and time which has been reserved earlier by someone else. 
We are running Joomla 3.3.1

Which Joomla extension can do it? I heard Breezing forms would need lot of custom code for this.

Thanks

Comment: Please be aware that by staying on Joomla 3.3.1, you're putting your users as risk. Please update to Joomla 4.3.5 immediately which fixes an important security vulnerability.

Comment: To avoid any confusions, @Lodder meant to say Joomla 3.4.5 and not 4.3.5 [**(Joomla 3.4.5 security release)**](https://www.joomla.org/announcements/release-news/5634-3-4-5-released.html)

Comment: And here I was thinking @Lodder was secretly working on J4.3.5 core and the rest of the J dev community was just playing catch up.

Comment: Thanks Lodder. I tried Akeeba backup to backup the website, but it failed so did not upgrade to 3.4.5. I need to find other free extensions for backing up.

Comment: Akeeba works fine, it could be an issue with the Akeeba config.
If you have issues, reduce the JPA-File size to 49mb, 20, 10 or 2MB. Everytime I had issues, it's all about the file size. You can start another stack question / thread and I will answer in detail.

Comment: Breezingforms offers a lot, same as DPCalendar, but I have started to develop my own custom components. All the big Joomla extensions seems to have a lack of usability (IMHO).

Answer (score 2):

Please goto http://extensions.joomla.org/ when looking for extensions.

I can think of two extensions- [Vik Appointments](http://www.extensionsforjoomla.com/extensions-for-joomla/vik-appointments-e4j) and [OS Services Booking](http://joomdonation.com/joomla-extensions/joomla-services-appointment-booking.html).

> **Vik Appointments** is an extension born to build a complete
> appointments-scheduler system for your Joomla website. Designed to
> schedule and organize appointments of any kind, for any kind of
> service, business that needs to have a reliable availability calendar.
> Accept reservations online and schedule the appointments for each
> employee in a smart and efficient way.
>
> **OS Services Booking** is Joomla online services schedule booking and
> appointments management. This extension has a lot of great features to
> make your services booking system helpful with the customers.

Disclaimer: I'm not affiliated with either software maker.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with most Events plugins. Just call the 'event' an interview. Set the number available for each day/time to 1 and no-one else can 'book' the slot.

Find an events plugin that will allow you to customise the pages/titles as required.

Any form plugin would require a lot of work to achieve the same thing.